# What could "blah" in "just give blah it blah a quick roll" be?

Tags: meaning

It sounds like the tutorial is [saying](https://youtu.be/rEnMEDo8Nzw?t=128) (a video link with a time stamp)

> placing it in an oiled bowl
>   just **give blah it blah** a quick roll around in the
>   oil, and covering with a damp cloth ...

I listened over and over again, and I cannot figure out what blah could be, could someone give a hint?

Answer (score 1):

"just givin' it a quick roll around..." is what I hear where *givin'* is just slang for *giving*.

Comment: givin' is not slang....but yes, it is: just giving it a quick roll around in the bowl

Answer (score 0):

What you are hearing is not a word.

Watch the video at the moment you refer to - the dough in the bowl visibly jumps, so some frames of the video have obviously been cut out. The audio has quite a bit of echo on it, which suggests it was recorded along with the video, rather than added later as a voiceover to the edited video.

It seems to be a **video editing mistake** - the video has been cut badly, and maybe part of a word, or parts of two words have been left in.