# "Wait until them cooled down completely", is this sentence clear, grammatical, and idiomatic? In particular, do I use the correct form of "cool"?

Tags: meaning

It sounds like the tutorial is [saying](https://youtu.be/rEnMEDo8Nzw?t=259) (a video link with a time stamp)

> so
>   this is what they should look like when
>   they're all done. **deal/till** them cool
>   completely

I am aware that the presenter waited until the bread cooled down to cut it. Although the "deal/till" part is not audible, so I rewrote the sentence as

> so
>   this is what they should look like when
>   they're all done. Wait until them **cooled** down completely.

Is my version clear, grammatical, and idiomatic? In particular, do I use the correct form of "cool"?

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly the same issue as [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/236943/what-could-blah-in-just-give-blah-it-blah-a-quick-roll-be/236955#236955) about the **same video**.

What you are hearing is just an example of **bad video editing**.

The creator has recorded the audio along with the video, so when they cut the video they cut the audio too. You're hearing a word, or part of a word that isn't meant to be there.

Comment: It sounds like 'let them cool completely' to me, but perhaps that's just what I would expect to hear.

Comment: @KateBunting If you look at the other linked question you'll definitely see (and hear) the bad editing. This one sounds a bit more like a word than the other, but I think it is pointless trying to identify it when I don't think it is meant to be there, or is is clipped by the editing.